# Visiting my partner in the USA. Will I run into any trouble using ESTA / VWP (Visa Waiver Program)

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

I'm from the UK and I've been to the USA once before. I want to go and spend the Christmas holidays with my girlfriend who is American. I am using the VWP which I have been approved for, but I am worried about my entry interview.

I have heard that CBP can reject people if they think that they plan to move to the USA, and that this is more common if you are visiting a partner.

How do I help the CBP agents see that I am planning on leaving within my visa stay? I will be providing return flight info and proof of income, is that enough?

Should my girlfriend come through immigration with me or should we go separately?

Comment: Will your girlfriend arrive with you into the States from the UK or are you joining her (and her family) there? Regardless of that, if I were you I would just go alone to the CBP and just tell them I'm visiting a friend and show them my return flight ticket if they ask. I guess having a job helps, too, as it seems to me that they ask you for your occupation at some point during the procedure, so do you have one?

Comment: She is arriving with me on the same flight. Yeah I am full time employed. I'm not sure I should say I'm visiting a "friend" as surely they might question if she's my girlfriend or not, or if I have one?

Comment: Then I think you should have a proof of employment on you just in case they ask (but I was never asked for such a document nor was any of the people I know that went to the US on a VWP), and go alone to the CBP officers.

Comment: What would you recommend as a proof of employment? Will a recent pay slip be enough?

Comment: A letter from your employer is best. As no one I know has ever encountered the situation this is only a guess, but I don't see why they would not accept a pay slip.

Comment: Where does your girlfriend live?

Comment: @phoog New York City

Comment: Agree with a friend (other than your GF) to hang out in NYC during your stay. Then approach CBP separately and truthfully claim you're meeting said friend during the holidays.

Comment: @JonathanReez that part is already true conveniently enough. That's whose address I put on my ESTA form. What do I say if I'm questioned about my girlfriend though?

Comment: Don't mention your GF and make sure you're not seen together in line. It may sound silly but that's probably the easiest option. Obviously if they ask a *direct* question you tell the truth.

Comment: Well I (US citizen) have entered the US with a VWP girlfriend and none of this came up, but I was living in Europe at the time, so it's not directly relevant.  The chance that you'll have a problem is small indeed, but it can't hurt to be prepared. Don't lie, though. If you do, you risk irritating the immigration officer. (We presented ourselves together in the US citizens' line.)